# Why am I getting this error when trying to configure rsyslog.conf?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to forward any system logs using `/etc/rsyslog.conf` pertaining to `ssh-server-g3*` will be written to a separate location and the file will have today's date in it as part of the filename.

This is what I have

```
ssh*                           /temp/logs/ssh.%$NOW%.log
```

I'm getting a syntax error but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a template in the rsyslog in order for this to work. I hope this will help others down the road.

```
template myTemplate,"/temp/logs/ssh.%$NOW%.log"

:programname, startswith, "ssh" ?myTemplate
```